# trying to use argparse in google colab, error: the following arguments are required

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, argparse, openmmlab

hi i tried codes for extracting optical flow from images frames(stored in google drive) using pwc-net algorithm in google colab as below:

```
from mmcv.utils import config
# Copyright (c) OpenMMLab. All rights reserved.
!pip install mmcv-full
!pip install mmflow
import os.path as osp
from argparse import ArgumentParser

import mmcv
# use the pre-trained model for the whole PWC-Net
load_from = 'https://download.openmmlab.com/mmflow/pwcnet/pwcnet_8x1_sfine_flyingthings3d_subset_384x768.pth'  # model path can be found in model zoo
from mmflow.apis import inference_model, init_model
from mmflow.datasets import visualize_flow, write_flow
parser = ArgumentParser()
img1='/content/drive/My Drive/resizedImages_river/frame1.jpg'
img2='/content/drive/My Drive/resizedImages_river/frame2.jpg'
config='configs/pwcnet/pwcnet_8x1_slong_flyingchairs_384x448.py'
checkpoint='checkpoints/pwcnet_8x1_slong_flyingchairs_384x448.pth'

parser.add_argument('img1', help='Image1 file')
parser.add_argument('img2', help='Image2 file')
parser.add_argument('--valid',help='Valid file. If the predicted flow is''sparse, valid mask will filter the output flow map.')
parser.add_argument('config', help='Config file')
parser.add_argument('checkpoint', help='Checkpoint file')
parser.add_argument('flow_map', help='Path of directory to save flow map and flow file')
parser.add_argument('--out_prefix',help='The prefix for the output results ''including flow file and visualized flow map',default='flow')
parser.add_argument('--device', default='cuda:0', help='Device used for inference')
args = parser.parse_args()
return args
def main(args):
    # build the model from a config file and a checkpoint file
  model = init_model(args.config, args.checkpoint, device=args.device)
# test a single image
result = inference_model(model, args.img1, args.img2)
result = inference_model(model, args.img1, args.img2, valids=args.valid)
# save the results
mmcv.mkdir_or_exist(args.flow_map)
visualize_flow(result, osp.join(args.flow_map, f'{args.out_prefix}.jpg'))
```

but google colab shows error message as below:

colab_kernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: img1, img2, config, checkpoint, flow_map
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

i searched google for fix this error, but i did not find any solution.I appreciate any help

Comment: The error is absolutely clear, isn't it?  When you run this script, you are required to provide those five command line parameters.  You are not doing so.  If you don't want to supply those parameters on the command line, then delete all of the ArgumentParser stuff.

Comment: Why are you using argparse?  What's it supposed to be doing for you? Don't copy someone else's code without trying to understand the basics of what it does it does, and how to use it.  Does the sorce anything its use with colab. Or how to run this script?

Comment: What did you search for? `argparse`, `required arguments` and `colab` (or jupyter notebook) errors have come up often (on SO) - because they aren't designed to work together.  The best fix is to use borrowed code as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run this from a command line, then just fake it by supplying all the arguments in an object.

```
class Dummy:
     pass

from mmflow.datasets import visualize_flow, write_flow
args = Dummy()
args.img1='/content/drive/My Drive/resizedImages_river/frame1.jpg'
args.img2='/content/drive/My Drive/resizedImages_river/frame2.jpg'
args.config='configs/pwcnet/pwcnet_8x1_slong_flyingchairs_384x448.py'
args.checkpoint='checkpoints/pwcnet_8x1_slong_flyingchairs_384x448.pth'
args.flow_map=??????  # You must supply this
args.device = "cuda:0"
args.out_prefix = "flow"

model = init_model(args.config, args.checkpoint, device=args.device)
result = inference_model(model, args.img1, args.img2)
result = inference_model(model, args.img1, args.img2, valids=args.valid)
mmcv.mkdir_or_exist(args.flow_map)
visualize_flow(result, osp.join(args.flow_map, f'{args.out_prefix}.jpg'))
```